# How to display image in GI

Tags: acumatica

How we can display images in GI screen, can anyone please let me know.
I have tried joining NoteDoc and UploadFile with InventoryItem and used FileID from UploadFile table but it is showing as text only but not image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in Generic Inquiry 'StockItemsImages' uses the grid Notes/File dialog to store the image:
[image]

You have to go through the dialog to see the image:
[image]

To display an image in a grid you would have to change the Type property of the PXGridColumn ASP control which is explained here:
[How to show images inside selector lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926127/how-to-show-images-inside-selector-lookup)

I'm not seing the option to change that from the Generic Inquiry interface but it could  be done with a Custom Inquiry as part of an Acumatica customization.

Comment: Thanks HB_Acumatica.