# Show image uploaded from Files on grid Acumatica

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I need to show image uploaded by users and show this on grid like the picture below:

[image]

At first, I use PXImageUploader for this column but it doesn't work. I can't upload image by using **Upload** button, only drag and drop and some problems with it. I think this way is not good.

Then, I use another way that is uploading images to Files, copy **External link** from SM202510 and paste to this column. It's OK but users have to perform too much steps to do that, it's kind of complicated for user so I want to find a way to get image link and paste automatically.

The problem is I can't find something like an event FieldUpdated with NoteID to get the image link when user uploaded the image.

Is there any way to do that or do you have a suggestion for me in this situation?

Comment: Something similar for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926127/how-to-show-images-inside-selector-lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For form container use `PXImageView` control.

For grid container you can use `PXGridColumn` element with `DisplayMode` and `Type` properties:

```
<px:PXGridColumn DataField="UsrImage" DisplayMode="Value" Type="Icon" />
```

Compose `External Link` URL with the file `UID` property and assign the URL string to the field displaying the image. I tested this method to show the first image that was attached to the grid record.

```
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public void SOLine_UsrImage_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        PX.SM.UploadFileMaintenance upload = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PX.SM.UploadFileMaintenance>();

        foreach (Guid noteId in PXNoteAttribute.GetFileNotes(sender, e.Row))
        {
            PX.SM.FileInfo fileInfo = upload.GetFile(noteId);

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileInfo.Name).ToLowerInvariant();

                if (fileExtension == ".png" || fileExtension == ".jpg" || fileExtension == ".jpeg" || fileExtension == ".gif")
                {
                    e.ReturnValue = string.Concat(PXUrl.SiteUrlWithPath(), "/Frames/GetFile.ashx?fileID=", fileInfo.UID.ToString());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]